# Typescript and Angular. Casting Scope Type?

Tags: angularjs, casting, scope, typescript, directive

In a directive I have some custom logic for extending a scope. To do this I create a child scope off the received scope.

```
$scope = scope.new(false);
```

But in typescript this is causing issues. I have an interface for my directives scope called `ITableScope` which extends `ng.IScope`. It is complaining that `ng.IScope` is not an assignable type to `ITableScope`.

```
interface ITableScope extends ng.IScope {}
var $scope: ITableScope;
$scope = scope.$new(false);
```

So I thought maybe I could cast `scope.$new` but it doesn't seem to know what I'm trying to do.

```
interface ITableScope extends ng.IScope {}
var $scope: ITableScope;
$scope = (ITableScope) scope.$new(false);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Syntax for type casting is `<ITableScope> scope.$new(false);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love it when I answer my own questions.

I was doing it all wrong. You cast with angle brackets.

```
$scope = <ITableScope> scope.$new(false);
```

Also, thank you to @musically_ut. I discovered it seconds after writing my post but you're response was very quick!